# SQL OUTPUT Parameter Not Assigning

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have the following SQL Statement written in SQL Server 2008 which isn't returning a value for the OUTPUT Parameter even though there is data in the table. I added static values and ran the query alone and it produced a record so I am not sure if it has something to do with my Stored Procedure or my VB.NET Code.

```
ALTER Procedure  [dbo].[GetGenInfo_Delete01_01_22]
@IDX int,
@FPath varchar(100) OUTPUT

AS

Begin
    SELECT @FPath = FilePath FROM GENINFO_E1_01_22 WHERE ID = @IDX  
    DELETE 
    FROM GenInfo_E1_01_22
    WHERE ID = @IDX

END
```

My VB Code

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(connstr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "GetGenInfo_Delete01_01_22"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("IDX", ID)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FPath", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)
        cmd.Parameters("@FPath").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        GridView1.DataBind()
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: You never read the value back out from the parameter in your VB.NET code. Not sure why you bind the the result of `ExecuteReader`, as it is empty.

Comment: Looks to be in your VB code.. After executing the SPROC you need to pull the out value from the parameter: DIm SomeString as string = cmd.Parameters("@FPath").value

Comment: @Oded: In/out is from SQL Server's perspective.  You don't read the value on an **in** parameter.

Comment: @Andomar - I meant in VB.NET, as you have shown in your answer.

Comment: @Oded: You mean VB.  But I see your point, the OP's code "never reads the value", not "you" in general.

Answer (score 3):

An output parameter does not show up in the result set.  So you can't read it with `ExecuteReader()`.

You can read it like:

```
Dim result as String = cmd.Parameters("@FPath").Value
```